# C# - How to create nuget package with references

Tags: c#, nuget, asp.net-core-2.1, .net-core-2.1

I have a solution with 5 projects, 2 are .netstandard 2.0 and 3 are .net core 2.1.
The references between the projects are as follows:

- Project `Api` references `Common` and `Models`.
- Project `Common` has no references.
- Project 'Logic' references `Common`, 'Models' and 'Interfaces'.
- Project `Interfaces` references `Models`.
- Project `Models` references `Common`.

I've added this `Api.nuspec` file in the root folder of the Api project where the `Api.csproj` file is:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<package >
  <metadata>
    <id>API</id>
    <version>1.0.0</version>
    <title>title</title>
    <authors>Liran Friedman</authors>
    <owners>Liran Friedman</owners>
    <licenseUrl></licenseUrl>
    <projectUrl></projectUrl>
    <iconUrl></iconUrl>
    <requireLicenseAcceptance>false</requireLicenseAcceptance>
    <description>desc</description>
    <releaseNotes>Initial version</releaseNotes>
    <copyright>Copyright 2018</copyright>
    <tags>api</tags>
    <dependencies>
      <group targetFramework=".NETCoreApp2.1">
        <dependency id="Logic" version="1.0.0" exclude="Analyzers" />
        <dependency id="Models" version="1.0.0" exclude="Analyzers" />
        <dependency id="Microsoft.AspNetCore" Version="2.1.4" exclude="Build,Analyzers" />
        <dependency id="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication" Version="2.1.2" exclude="Build,Analyzers" />
        <dependency id="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies" Version="2.1.2" exclude="Build,Analyzers" />
        <dependency id="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer" Version="2.1.2" exclude="Build,Analyzers" />
        <dependency id="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization" Version="2.1.2" exclude="Build,Analyzers" />
        <dependency id="Microsoft.AspNetCore.CookiePolicy" Version="2.1.2" exclude="Build,Analyzers" />
        <dependency id="Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection" Version="2.1.1" exclude="Build,Analyzers" />
        <dependency id="Newtonsoft.Json" Version="11.0.2" exclude="Build,Analyzers" />
        <dependency id="System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt" Version="5.2.4" exclude="Build,Analyzers" />
      </group>
    </dependencies>
  </metadata>
  <files>
    <file src="C:\XXX\Api\bin\Release\netcoreapp2.1\Api.dll" target="lib\netcoreapp2.1\Api.dll" />
    <file src="C:\XXX\Logic\bin\Release\netcoreapp2.1\Logic.dll" target="lib\netcoreapp2.1\Logic.dll" />
    <file src="C:\XXX\Models\bin\Release\netcoreapp2.1\Models.dll" target="lib\netcoreapp2.1\Models.dll" />
  </files>
</package>
```

I'm trying to create a nuget package for project `Api` and publish it to a local shared folder in our work network. I tried both ways:

- Right-clicking the project and select `pack`
- running on cmd: `nuget.exe pack Api.csproj -Build -IncludeReferencedProjects -Version 1.0.0 -OutputDirectory O:\Nugets -Properties Configuration=Release;Desc="desc";Authors="Liran Friedman"`

When I reference the nuget on my local PC it works fine, but when referencing it from other PC's it gives error `NU1101` saying that `Models' and`Logic` references are missing.

What am I doing wrong here?